# Not able to publish to a newly registered user's facebook feed. Works for an old user of the app.

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

We have taken this permission: publish_stream from the users.

The thing is that for the old users - our app is able to publish on their feed but it's not working for the new users we have registered.

What could be causing this? How can we fix it?

P.S. Let us know if you want to see some code, we are using python in the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the new o-auth, the access tokens have become of length 0-255 characters. Our access token field was of 100 characters. As result a few users could post data i.e. ones with access token less than 100 characters in length. For others it was not working. We changed the fields and it started working just fine.

P.S. :- SQLite database does not consider character or any limits put on the database. i.e. If you declare a field of say 100 chars max, and try to store a variable with 200 chars it will store it.

Comment: Note that access tokens will end up larger than 255 characters.  Please don't limit the size of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Please try going to the wall and clicking on Everyone( Most recent) or latest posts.. I have faced a similar issue, and the feeds are not visible but notifications used to come about the post. Also make sure after you post to the feed, you get the post id..

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at the response of the call that publishes the post to the user's stream.  What does it say?  Is it an error code?  Or a post Id?

Comment: Its a error code. But using that error code it is not possible to determine the issue exactly.

Comment: Can you post the web response here for us to look at?

Comment: Hi,
The issue has been solved. The problem was with the access token. Which have become of variable length ranging from 0 - 255 characters(o-auth). Our database had char limit of 100. 
The old users had access token of length less than 100 and new user more than 100 characters. So new user were not able to post anything.